# Sync Gradle offile (manually)

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to start a new project in android studio.
when the IDE tries to sync with gradle, I'm getting ERROR 503 (my company's firewall blocks the connection).
I'm able to download the file manually, but i can't figure how to update it manually so the "Grade project sync failed..." error will be gone.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the exact error output?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved when i updated the settings via SDK manager and not via Android Studio's welcome wizard